# Rsync a directory without its contents

Tags: directory, rsync

I need to preserve the directory's attributes, and I'm limited to using rsync for compatibility. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Until I find a better solution, `rsync -a --include='*/' --exclude='*' dir\src tmp\`, deleting all the subdirectories, then moving the directory where it needs to go.